# Migrate an app to Durandal on a piecemeal basis?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

I am working with a client that has based the architecture of their application on a course on Pluralsite from Miguel Castro (http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/building-multi-client-end-to-end-service-oriented-applications)

If the app were going to be serving data to many different systems, I could understand the desire for this framework, however it is simple intended to be a SPA.  I am wanting to move the app (for maintainabilty and speed) to a Durandal based application.  I am wanting to attack it on a piece by piece basis however.

Is it possible to set up Durandal for the system, but not have the entire app under it yet?  For example, say the app was a CRM.  I want to optimize the scheduler component to only load what is needed on demand and to reduce the amount of data being loaded/returned.  I don't want to touch the "Customer List/Add" section yet.  I will eventually.  Can I have the Scheduler running in Durandal but the Customers not, all within the same app?

I hope I explained this well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if I understand you correctly.

A core part of the Durandal framework is binding partials to client side controllers (called view models) and displaying them according to client side routing. It is possible, however, to render only html pages.

One strategy you may use is to create empty javascript object literals `{}` as your view models for pages that are not Durandal enabled. This will bind the existing page as a partial according to the client side route.

You can read more here:

http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router.html

http://durandaljs.com/documentation/View-Location.html

Answer (score 0):

If the app you are building is going to always be on the web(no port to a phone or tablet) then you can just create mini spas for the areas you need to convert and leave the other areas in what ever technology you want (MVC/Nancy/Webforms).  In your example, the scheduler part of the app can be a single html page that loads durandal and contains all the screens needed for scheduling.  This part of the app will be fast and use ajax calls to the back end.  The part of the app for crud customer stuff can be standard web get/post over forms.  This might be a good long term solution as it would give you the best of both worlds.  I have done this on a project and it works well.  I setup it up as an asp.net mvc app.  The front customer facing side is all MVC\Razor and the admin area is Durandal.  I created a folder on the root of my site called SPAS and inside that I have an admin folder that contains my main.js.  This admin folder is an entire durandal app with its own shell and views.  To get to this page I added a controller and route "/Admin" on my site.  Going to this route will render a view with html and my activation script for requirejs to start the durandal app.

```
<body>
    <div id="applicationHost"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/require.js" data-main="/SPAS/Admin/main"></script>
</body>
```

You could easily add multiple folder inside the spas folder each containing an isolated durandal app.

Comment: We use this approach in our application as well. Apparently, this technique has been named "SPA Silos" - http://theodybrothers.blogspot.com/2014/11/spa-silos.html?m=1